# How can I connect to a port on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, udp, port, telnet, firewall

I am trying to make a simple chat application.

I asked my friend to install the application on his Windows 7 laptop.

Let say his public ip address is: 500.500.500

My chat program starts listening to port on 10007. In his computer I tried

telnet localhost 10007
then sent some text, and the text was seen in the chat application.

But when I tried telnet 500.500.500 10007 from my computer, telnet: Could not open connection to the host, on port 10007

I tried disabling both my firewall and his and also I have opened port following the guide here:http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html

What can it be that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

his public address on the internet is actually the address of his provider (e.g cable modem/DSL), you would need to configure HIS router to forward port 10007 to his local/private IP address for this to work.

Comment: Can you give details please? Or maybe a link on how to do this?

Comment: what kind of router do you have?

Comment: I have no idea. I do not even know what kinds are available so I really do not get the question actually. Sorry :)

Comment: He has a wireless modem.

Comment: you mean he has an air card?  like a verizon or at&t card??  or do you mean he has a wifi home connection?

Comment: I mean a home wi-fi modem. Something like this: http://www.uruninceleme.com/db/resimler/urun88_AirTies_rt211_onyuz.jpg

Comment: ok, that home wi-fi is connected to what?  lol....  try this.. have your friend physically plug into his wifi router (not a modem), go to a browser and type:   http://192.168.1.1

Comment: I think it is both a modem and a router. I see a page asking for password. The exact model is this I believe: ZyXEL P-660N-T1A

Comment: try, id: admin  pwd: password

Comment: you need to research this, lol... not me (I would appreciate the up vote though)... you want to do PORT FORWARDING,  have your friend do an IP config, that IP address is the private address that you need to have your router forward port 10007 messages.

Comment: Thanks, I see a page full of options. Can you send me an example of what I should be doing? I can maybe figure out the rest?

Comment: Thanks, so what I need is port forwarding.

Comment: What is a better title for this question? So that people can find when searched?